Ubuntu 24.04 default partitioning
I would like to install Ubuntu on an empty 1 TB hard drive, alongside my Windows installation on a different disk. However, I don't want to use all of the disk space, but only around 250 GB. Hence, as far as I can tell, I need to choose "Manual partitioning" during the installation process. I would like to use the same "default" partitioning the installer would have used if I had chosen "Erase disk and install Ubuntu", but only for the aforementioned part of the disk. I would assume that's the partitioning the Ubuntu developers would recommend to most "normal users".
So what is this default partitioning? I can't find any information about that at all. Different sources recommend different partitionings, a lot of information seems to be outdated (e.g., many guides recommend using a swap partition of varying size, but I've seen opinions that this was outdated and now swap files are preferred, which don't require a separate partition). Some claim there is no "default partitioning", but what else would you call the partitioning that the Ubuntu installer chooses when doing "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu alongside ..."? Or is it different for different hardware setups? But I don't know what the factors could be, and I haven't found any information on that.
I can't for the life of me understand why there seems to be no official documentation on this "default partitioning" with exact sizes of the partitions. Or why there isn't a "default" preset for the "Manual partitioning" install option, which would make things easier to understand. It seems to leave the users with a bit of unnecessary guesswork, in my opinion.

How is the drive empty if Windows is on it?

Oh, Windows is on a different disk. Thanks, I will clear that up.

How can you set up default if space available is unknown. I have had it install to unallocated on other drive, so only use Something Else or Manual install options. For new users default is recommended, but that mostly assumes you are dual booting on same drive as Windows, so / is not huge. With new multi TB drives that can make / too large. Most select / & separate /home or data partition(s) if using lots of space. But /home or data sizes are opinion based and depend a lot on planned use. Installs now are UEFI using gpt partitioning unless drive seen as old MBR.

I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 using the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option on the empty 1 TB HDD, and this is the partitioning the installer had chosen:
/dev/sda:

/dev/sda1: /boot/efi (fat32), exactly 1075 MiB (~1.05 GiB), but only ~8.26 MiB (~1%) are used
/dev/sda2: / (ext4), remaining space on hard-drive.

For some reason, /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell is also listed as mount point for sda2, I don't know what it is for.
So apparently this is what Ubuntu 2024.04 is using by default, a boot loader partition of around 1 GiB (which can be added during the manual partitioning) and the rest of the remaining space is attributed to a second partition with / as a mount point.

Why not? The question was about the "default partitioning" schema the Ubuntu 2024.04 would use for an empty disk, something I couldn't find official information on. I've added another paragraph to clarify the relation to the question.

After you install ubuntu then boot up using a LiveUSB memory stick and run either gparted or disks to resize the ubuntu partition to reduce its footprint
